# Parsing this JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have been provided with this JSON string in my database, and I'm trying to find out how could I parse it as an array, as from using the json_decode function I am not getting an array from this string.

The provided string:

```
a:2:{s:9:"languages";a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:8:"Spaniola";s:7:"scriere";s:9:"Incepator";s:6:"citire";s:5:"Mediu";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}i:1;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:7:"Germana";s:7:"scriere";s:9:"Incepator";s:6:"citire";s:9:"Incepator";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}i:2;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:7:"Engleza";s:7:"scriere";s:5:"Mediu";s:6:"citire";s:7:"Avansat";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}}s:6:"others";a:9:{s:13:"limba_materna";s:6:"Romana";s:16:"categorie_permis";s:30:"a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"B";}";s:19:"an_categorie_permis";s:4:"2005";s:10:"operare_pc";s:7:"Avansat";s:18:"programe_aplicatii";s:0:"";s:10:"comunicare";s:0:"";s:21:"competente_organizare";s:0:"";s:9:"descriere";s:0:"";s:20:"cursuri_specializari";s:0:"";}}
```

I am also using silex as micro-framework if it's relevant.

Comment: This is no JSON, this is a serialized array. Just `unserialize()` it

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept one of the answers. This helps to keep the site clean! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a JSON string, this is a serialized array.
You need to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) it!

```
var_dump(unserialize('a:2:{s:9:"languages";a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:8:"Spaniola";s:7:"scriere";s:9:"Incepator";s:6:"citire";s:5:"Mediu";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}i:1;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:7:"Germana";s:7:"scriere";s:9:"Incepator";s:6:"citire";s:9:"Incepator";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}i:2;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:7:"Engleza";s:7:"scriere";s:5:"Mediu";s:6:"citire";s:7:"Avansat";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}}s:6:"others";a:9:{s:13:"limba_materna";s:6:"Romana";s:16:"categorie_permis";s:30:"a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"B";}";s:19:"an_categorie_permis";s:4:"2005";s:10:"operare_pc";s:7:"Avansat";s:18:"programe_aplicatii";s:0:"";s:10:"comunicare";s:0:"";s:21:"competente_organizare";s:0:"";s:9:"descriere";s:0:"";s:20:"cursuri_specializari";s:0:"";}}'));
```

> array(2) { ["languages"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["limba_straina"]=> string(8) "Spaniola" ["scriere"]=> string(9) "Incepator" ["citire"]=> string(5) "Mediu" ["vorbire"]=> string(7) "Avansat" } [1](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php)=> array(4) { ["limba_straina"]=> string(7) "Germana" ["scriere"]=> string(9) "Incepator" ["citire"]=> string(9) "Incepator" ["vorbire"]=> string(7) "Avansat" } [2]=> array(4) { ["limba_straina"]=> string(7) "Engleza" ["scriere"]=> string(5) "Mediu" ["citire"]=> string(7) "Avansat" ["vorbire"]=> string(7) "Avansat" } } ["others"]=> array(9) { ["limba_materna"]=> string(6) "Romana" ["categorie_permis"]=> string(30) "a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"B";}" ["an_categorie_permis"]=> string(4) "2005" ["operare_pc"]=> string(7) "Avansat" ["programe_aplicatii"]=> string(0) "" ["comunicare"]=> string(0) "" ["competente_organizare"]=> string(0) "" ["descriere"]=> string(0) "" ["cursuri_specializari"]=> string(0) "" } }

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `JSON` string But It's `serialized` array:

```
$str = 'a:2:{s:9:"languages";a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:8:"Spaniola";s:7:"scriere";s:9:"Incepator";s:6:"citire";s:5:"Mediu";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}i:1;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:7:"Germana";s:7:"scriere";s:9:"Incepator";s:6:"citire";s:9:"Incepator";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}i:2;a:4:{s:13:"limba_straina";s:7:"Engleza";s:7:"scriere";s:5:"Mediu";s:6:"citire";s:7:"Avansat";s:7:"vorbire";s:7:"Avansat";}}s:6:"others";a:9:{s:13:"limba_materna";s:6:"Romana";s:16:"categorie_permis";s:30:"a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"B";}";s:19:"an_categorie_permis";s:4:"2005";s:10:"operare_pc";s:7:"Avansat";s:18:"programe_aplicatii";s:0:"";s:10:"comunicare";s:0:"";s:21:"competente_organizare";s:0:"";s:9:"descriere";s:0:"";s:20:"cursuri_specializari";s:0:"";}}';

$arr = unserialize($str);
print_r($arr);
```